# How to save Phonegap Inapp browser content onto the parent application for offline viewing

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I Am building a phonegap project with PGB that uses an inapp browser to draw content from a site online , I would like to scrape some of that content that is loaded in the inapp browser and save it for offline access by the user on the app.
I have managed to post data to the site and get a response but I cant save the data on the app.

```
function loadStopCallBack3() {

 if (inAppBrowserRef != undefined) {

   inAppBrowserRef.insertCSS({ code: " .highlight{background-color: yellow !important;}" });

    var options = {
        retrieveLocId : 'FAOR FACT',

    };
    var script2='$("#IAgree").dialog(\'close\');var form = document.createElement("form");form.setAttribute("action","https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/queryRetrievalMapAction.do");';
    script2+='form.setAttribute(\'method\',"post");';
    script2+='var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "retrieveLocId");hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "FAOR");form.appendChild(hiddenField);';
    script2+=' hiddenField = document.createElement("input");hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "reportType");hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "Report");form.appendChild(hiddenField);';
    script2+=' hiddenField = document.createElement("input");hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "actionType");hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "notamRetrievalByICAOs");form.appendChild(hiddenField);';
    script2+='form.submit();';

   inAppBrowserRef.executeScript(
   {  code : script2},
      function(returnval){
        console.log("----------------->"+returnval);                                
      }

   );

     inAppBrowserRef.show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large your data is and the type of usage, you can simply store the data in `localstorage` or `web sql.`

Both are supported in HTML5 and Phonegap apps and can be accessed offline.